# Как отсортировать, чтобы сначала были русские слова

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker

есть столбец с русскими и английскими словами, при сортировке

> SELECT * FROM "public"."table" ORDER BY "title" ASC;

или так

> SELECT * FROM "public"."radio" ORDER BY "title" COLLATE "ru_RU" ASC;

сначала идут английские слова а затем русские, а надо наоборот.

В контейнере установлена ru локаль.

locale

```
LANG=ru_RU.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.utf8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.utf8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.utf8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

locale -a

```
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
ru_RU.utf8
```

База данных инициализирована с ru локалью

```
select datname, 
       datcollate
from pg_database;

postgres    ru_RU.utf8
site    ru_RU.utf8
template1   ru_RU.utf8
template0   ru_RU.utf8
```

Comment: Сначала сортировать по наличию кириллических символов, а потом по алфавиту.

Comment: А может есть пример? или ссылка на документацию про это?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM "public"."table" ORDER BY CASE WHEN ("title" ~ '[АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя]') then 0 else 1 end ASC, "title" ASC;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]